# nested form, empty symbol for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms

So, after I have migrated our application from rails 2 to 3.2, I’ve implemented a nested form for a new class, which has worked perfectly.

Unfortunately, I cannot get the same to work with a migrated class and it's keeping me on the edge for days now.

Parent model:

```
class Geodatensatz < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name =  "GEODATENSATZ”
self.sequence_name = "GEODATENSATZ_SEQU"
attr_accessible :anwendungseinschraenkungs_attributes  
has_many :anwendungseinschraenkung,
 :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :anwendungseinschraenkung,
                              :reject_if => lambda  { |a| a[:beschreibung].blank? },
                              :allow_destroy => true
```

Child Model:

```
class Anwendungseinschraenkung < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = "ANWENDUNGSEINSCHRAENKUNG"            
self.sequence_name =  "ANWENDUNGSEINSCHRAENKUNG_SEQU"   

attr_accessible :geodatensatz_id, :beschreibung, :index

belongs_to :geodatensatz
```

in the view:

```
<%= form.fields_for :anwendungseinschraenkung do |builder| %>
                <%= builder.text_area :beschreibung, :rows => 3 %>
<% end %>
```

I can get all “anwendungseinschraenkung” by typing “@geodatensatz.anwendungseinschraenkung”, but the :anwendungseinschraenkung seems to be empty. If I call @geodatensatz.anwendungseinschraenkung.build, the single Object with “nil” for all attribute values is constructed.

thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay... so as soon as I changed from

```
<%= form_for :geodatensatz .....
```

to

```
<%= form_for @geodatensatz ....
```

the fields_for displayed :)

I'm sure, someone who knows a bit more about ROR can elaborate on the reasons for this....